# Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes - Android studio 2.0 beta 6

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I updated to the last version of Android studio 2.0 Beta 6 with the gradle :

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta6'
}
```

The app works perfectly fine on emulator and devices I tested every thing and it works fine.

I got many errors only when I try to Generate Signed APK,

I got some errors in dependencies, all of them solved when i excluded vector drawable, vector animate drawable and Support-v4 library

Now i dont have any dependencies error.

now my gradle.build for the app module looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    configurations {
        //all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        all*.exclude module: 'animated-vector-drawable'
        all*.exclude module: 'support-vector-drawable'
        //all*.exclude module: 'support-v4'

    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.test"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"

//        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'animated-vector-drawable'
        exclude module: 'support-vector-drawable'
    }
    compile('com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'animated-vector-drawable'
        exclude module: 'support-vector-drawable'
    }
    compile('com.android.support:palette-v7:23.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.android.support:design:23.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.2.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    compile('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:2.5.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'

    }
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
}
```

The errors shows up only when I build for release:

This is the error when i turn on multiDex:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

And this is the error when i turn it off:

```
:app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I tried to change the `buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'` to every possible version and nothing changed.

when i put the version 22.0.1 i got this error:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: name already added: string{"a"}

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I tried with all possible support libraries version and same result.

I tried with Java 1.6 and 1.7 and nothing has changed !

what can be other possible solution please ?

Comment: I got the same error when i have two classes with same class name. solved by changing name

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I also faced the same error, and i was searching through many existing answers with duplicate dependencies or multidex etc. but none worked. (Android studio 2.0 Beta 6, Build tools 23.0.2, no multidex)

It turned out that i once used a package names which didn't match the package name that is depicted in the Manifest.

In other ParseException lines, i found out that i had files in different modules whith similiar package names/paths that possibly conflicted the dexer.

**Example:**

Module A: *com.example.xyz.ticketing.modulea.Interface.java*

Module B: *com.example.Xyz.ticketing.moduleb.Enumerations.java*

Module C: Has dependencies on A and B

After fixing "Xyz" to lowercase, the dexer was fine again.

**How to find out:**

When i looked through the output of the gradle console for the **ParseExceptions** that looks like this:

*AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error converting bytecode to dex:\nCause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes"*

I scrolled close to the end of the exception. There is a part in that long exception line that actually mentions the cause:

*Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (at/dummycompany/mFGM/hata/hwp/BuildConfig) does not match path (at/dummycompany/mfgm/hata/hwp/BuildConfig.class)*

This way i found out where to search for missmatching package names/paths

Comment: actuallu i did 2 thing at the same tim, 1- i modified my proguard and added all possible option i found on internet, 2- i did change the package names as u suggested, im not sure which is the solution... thank you

Comment: Nice to hear that it worked for you. I also looked out for proguard errors. The solutions didn't solve the problem for me, but definitely also worth a try.

Comment: Great find. I had an incorrect capital letter in the 'applicationId' variable in my projects build.gradle file.

Answer (score 82):

just do `Build > Clean Project` 
Wait for Cleaning Ends and then `Build > Rebuild Project`, and the error was gone. that's it.

Comment: I had the same error message and this helped me to resolve the problem. Thanks. And I certainly had the correct package in my manifest.

Comment: helped me too. This is a problem of file name being non-case-sensitive on some systems

Comment: helped me three! ;)

Comment: thanks! I had this problem after renaming a package from Chronos to chronos... your solutions solved it!

Comment: This problem sometimes occurs when we reconstruct our project & package structure, in this situation we need to Clean and Rebuilding project.

Answer (score 10):

The solution for me is to modifing the Build Gradle file.
I found out, that the problem is a GC overhead (out of memory).

So I add some code to my configuration

```
android {
  dexOptions {
    incremental = true;
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
  } 
}
```

There is some other problem with proguard.
You've to set minifyEnabled to false also.

Comment: preDexLibraries false helped, thanks! Android Studio 2.3.3 with buildToolsVersion 26.0.2 buided ok, but when trying to RUN gave and error

Answer (score 3):

I had a wrong package name in one of the helper class,hence I was having the error.So check all the Classes and make sure you have correct package name.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was different, I was added these lines in `proguard-rules.pro`

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-overloadaggressively
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
```

Make sure to update everything from SDK manager as well.

Comment: checking progaurd was very important point in solving this issue .. shukran habib

Comment: @MBH It's my pleasure, habib :)

Answer (score 2):

If your targetSdkVersion is 25 or higher version and you use JDK 8 you have to add in your build.gradle file the following:

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 26
   buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...        
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37294741

Answer (score 1):

Removing `-overloadaggressively` from my `proguard-rules.pro` fixed this for me.

Alternatively, adding `-useuniqueclassmembernames` also fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried `./gradlew clean build`, Invalidating studio cache, restarting machine. But what solved the issue is **turning Instant run off**

Answer (score 0):

Got this issue while using the Android studio **template** for Login activity.
I've selected "activity" package to put my activity into.
The template in **AndroidManifest.xml**, instead of `.activity.LoginActivity` used the `.LoginActivity` thus causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you faced this error, certainly your package in manifest differ from the others that you have set in your classes. be careful.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today and the problem was that in my Constants.java classed I have defined (by mistake)

```
public static final class Checkout {
.......
}
```

and

```
public static final class CHECKOUT {
......
}
```

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise, be sure you tailor your answer to *this* question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will take care of this in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a class that I made that I didn't use yet. So I have to delete the class or use the class.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error. Appears that its due to renaming a package to lower case and a class had the previous case wording.

Answer (score -1):

Your gradle.build file will contain

```
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.2.1.jar')

compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'

compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
```

By removing this line from file.

```
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.2.1.jar')
```

It will work fine.