# Android Studio 2.1 Error converting bytecode to dex

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting the following error since I updated the android studio from 2.0 to 2.1.

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
>
> Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code. This is caused by
>   library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above. If
>   you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
>   targetCompatibility = '1.7' sourceCompatibility = '1.7' to that
>   submodule's build.gradle file.

I tried adding the following snippet in build.gradle, but still the issue persists

```
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
```

I saw some of the questions similar to this, but neither of the questions answered. Can anyone help me to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any java-only modules in your project?

Comment: No. I am not using any such modules. I had solved this by replacing the SDK with the old one. Now the studio is working fine.

Comment: Which SDK u replaced to solve this, Please can you explain how u solved it.

Comment: @Adi I replaced with the previous SDK that I had before updating the latest SDK. I had the copy of the older SDK.

Answer (score 33):

Try

```
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
        targetCompatibility = "1.7"
    }
}
```

in the main `build.gradle` file

Comment: Saved me a couple of hours of pain. Thank you!

Comment: Working great! Thanks.

Comment: not working for me!!
I am trying to create and encrypt a pdf file using itext and I m getting the same error
@sbeliakov

Answer (score 2):

Remove the dependencies from build.gradle, comment relevant code and then compile and clean your project.

After a successful clean add the dependencies again and uncomment what you commented after removing the dependencies earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Possibile duplicate of [Android: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020413/android-dex-cannot-parse-version-52-byte-code). The most quoted answer solved the problem for me.
I added compileOptions and jackOptions as shown below to my build.gradle to use JDK 1.8.

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...        
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```