# Android studio(2.1.1 April 28-2016) Strange Error converting bytecode to dex. Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to build my project and get this strange error (cause all worked perfectly in previous AS versions)

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
```

I understand that the problem is that (as the error tells me) some of my dependencies was compiled with java ver.8 but how I know which one of them?

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.app.mysuperapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            setRoot('src/test')
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7

    //<!-- TestFrameWork
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1-rc1'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'
    //----Materal design libs
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile('com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'library'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
    //<--
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
    compile('com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.8') {
        exclude group: 'xmlpull', module: 'xmlpull'
    }
    //----LogBack&SLF4J
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
    compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-5'
    compile('com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-5') {
        // workaround issue #73
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
    }
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
}
```

I've googled alredy similar questions on SO (like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084912/android-studio-2-1-error-converting-bytecode-to-dex) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020413/android-dex-cannot-parse-version-52-byte-code)) but adding this lines to build gradle

```
dependencies {

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
}
```

didn't solve my problem. I am pretty stuck and I need someone help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is **compile('com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.8')** that depends on Java 8

Version **1.4.7** doesn't depend on Java8, so if you can live with 1.4.7 the fix is quite simple.

Comment: @whizzzkey - How did you solve it? sebas - how did you know which package that didn't depend on JAVA 8?

Comment: @dazza5000 My project doesn't have a dependency on Java8, but when I updated a few libraries and got the error in the of this question I had to start reverting the updates until I found the culprit. Here is more info: http://xstream.10960.n7.nabble.com/Using-XStream-1-4-8-in-android-4-4-fails-td8932.html