# Android Studio run app java error

Tags: java, android

when I run my android app i have 3 errors

1)

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
```

2)

```
Error:1 error; aborting
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
```

3)

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: did you try to `clean project` then `rebuild project`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 2.1 Error converting bytecode to dex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084912/android-studio-2-1-error-converting-bytecode-to-dex)

Comment: yes, i did it @mgcaguioa

Comment: i have alredy 

`compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }`

and

`allprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
        targetCompatibility = "1.7"
    }
}`

and the error still @Arjan

Comment: if your using `google play services`, this link might help you >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890257/android-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexforrelease

Comment: *"This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above."*.  Which dependency is compiled using Java 8?  Including your gradle.build might enable someone to help you.  There's some more info on these pages http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020413/android-dex-cannot-parse-version-52-byte-code http://stackoverflow.com/a/36975041/6178459  
Suggested solutions are either to compile the entire project as java 8 or downgrade the dependency.  Also possibly related,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028438/gradle-sourcecompatibility-has-no-effect-to-subprojects