# Error converting bytecode to dex:

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I am facing this error since i have updated my android studio to 2.2.1.

> Error: Error converting bytecode to dex:
>   Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
>   This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.

So far i have tried:

1. cleaning and building the project
2. adding " sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
           targetCompatibility = "1.7" "
   to the gradle file.

Can anyone suggest how to solve this problem.

Comment: can you post your gradle file?

Answer (score 1):

You should use JDK **[1.8.0_92](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u92-relnotes-2949471.html)**

You are getting

> Error: Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code. This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.

Then you can set below in your **gradle** section .

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
```

**Clean-Rebuild**. Hope this helps you .

For better answer you can visit **[Android: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020413/android-dex-cannot-parse-version-52-byte-code)**

Comment: Hi,I cannot able to resolve same kind of exception.Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720018/obfuscation-minifyenabled-true-not-working-in-debug-and-release