# Obfuscation (minifyEnabled true) not working in Debug and Release

Tags: android, encryption, obfuscation

I cannot able to run apk using minifyEnabled true in Debug and Release mode.I have referred below links but none worked for me.

1.[Android- Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890257/android-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexforrelease)

2.[Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes - Android studio 2.0 beta 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35680979/error-converting-bytecode-to-dex-cause-java-lang-runtimeexception-exception-p)

Below is application build.gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'XX.XX.XXX'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true



    }



    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs' //integrate your libs from libs instead of jniLibs
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }


    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'

    }
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //    compile files('libs/maflogonimo-1.210.3.jar')
    compile project(':android-logging-log4j-1.0.3')
    compile project(':log4j-1.2.17')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.6.2.jar')
    //compile files('libs/javarosa-libraries-2015-09-02.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'

    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fcm:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    //    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    //compile files('libs/hellocharts-library-1.5.8.jar')
    compile 'com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.8-1'
    //GIS

    compile(name:'ClientHubSLL-3.16.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'ClientLog-3.16.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'Common-3.16.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'Connectivity-3.16.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'CoreServices-3.16.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'DataVaultLib-3.16.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'E2ETrace-3.16.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'HttpConvAuthFlows-3.16.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'HttpConversation-3.16.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'MAFLogger-3.16.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'MAFLogonCore-3.16.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'ODataAPI-3.16.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'ODataOnline-3.16.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'Request-3.16.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'SupportabilityFacade-3.16.1', ext:'aar')

    compile(name:'MAFCalendar-3.16.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'MAFLocaleAwareControls-3.16.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'MAFLogViewer-3.16.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'MAFSettingScreen-3.16.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'MAFTreeView-3.16.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'MAFUIComponents-3.16.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'XscriptParser-3.16.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'MAFLogonUI-3.16.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'MobilePlace-3.16.1', ext:'aar')

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Below is proguard-rules.pro file

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile, LineNumberTable
-keepattributes Exceptions, Signature

-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes InnerClasses

-keep class org.javarosa.** { *; }
-keep class com.sap.** { *; }

-keep class jcifs.** { *; }


-dontwarn com.google.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn com.sap.**
-dontwarn au.com.bytecode.**
-dontwarn org.joda.**
-dontwarn android.content.**
-dontwarn android.graphics.**
-dontwarn android.util.**
-dontwarn android.view.**

-dontwarn javax.servlet.**
-dontwarn jcifs.http.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.**
```

Below exception while running from command line

```
cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:366)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad descriptor: charOffset
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.AttributeListParser.parse(AttributeListParser.java:156)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.AttributeListParser.parseIfNecessary(AttributeListParser.java:115)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.AttributeListParser.getEndOffset(AttributeListParser.java:96)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.MemberListParser.parse(MemberListParser.java:213)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.MemberListParser.parseIfNecessary(MemberListParser.java:108)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.MethodListParser.getList(MethodListParser.java:54)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:542)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad descriptor: charOffset
        at com.android.dx.rop.type.Type.intern(Type.java:330)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:248)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:223)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotationsList(AnnotationParser.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.AnnotationParser.parseParameterAttribute(AnnotationParser.java:127)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.StdAttributeFactory.runtimeVisibleParameterAnnotations(StdAttributeFactory.java:666)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.StdAttributeFactory.parse0(StdAttributeFactory.java:162)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.AttributeFactory.parse(AttributeFactory.java:96)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.AttributeListParser.parse(AttributeListParser.java:141)
        ... 25 more

16:35:57.798 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] 1 error; aborting
16:35:57.800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'
16:35:57.801 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease FAILED
16:35:57.804 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 1 mins 1.425 secs.
16:35:57.807 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]] finished, busy: 14 mins 11.51 secs, idle: 0.078 secs
16:35:57.870 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
16:35:57.871 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
16:35:57.872 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
16:35:57.872 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
16:35:57.872 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
16:35:57.873 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
16:35:57.874 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
16:35:57.875 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
16:35:57.877 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
16:35:57.878 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
16:35:57.878 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
16:35:57.880 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
16:35:57.880 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 14 mins 46.244 secs
16:35:57.930 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache fileHashes.bin (D:\myJobCard_SourceCode\.gradle\2.10\taskArtifacts\fileHashes.bin)
16:35:57.931 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache fileSnapshots.bin (D:\myJobCard_SourceCode\.gradle\2.10\taskArtifacts\fileSnapshots.bin)
16:35:57.932 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache taskArtifacts.bin (D:\myJobCard_SourceCode\.gradle\2.10\taskArtifacts\taskArtifacts.bin)
16:35:57.933 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache outputFileStates.bin (D:\myJobCard_SourceCode\.gradle\2.10\taskArtifacts\outputFileStates.bin)
16:35:57.933 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on task history cache (D:\myJobCard_SourceCode\.gradle\2.10\taskArtifacts).
16:35:57.935 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache jarSnapshots.bin (C:\Users\MY HOME\.gradle\caches\2.10\jarSnapshots\jarSnapshots.bin)
16:35:57.935 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on jar snapshots cache (C:\Users\MY HOME\.gradle\caches\2.10\jarSnapshots).
16:35:57.937 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache classAnalysis.bin (C:\Users\MY HOME\.gradle\caches\2.10\classAnalysis\classAnalysis.bin)
16:35:57.937 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on class analysis cache (C:\Users\MY HOME\.gradle\caches\2.10\classAnalysis).
16:35:57.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on cp_settings class cache for settings file 'D:\myJobCard_SourceCode\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\MY HOME\.gradle\caches\2.10\scripts\settings_erwoxweslgmu8miqym6kcb1dt\cp_settings).
16:35:57.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on settings class cache for settings file 'D:\myJobCard_SourceCode\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\MY HOME\.gradle\caches\2.10\scripts\settings_erwoxweslgmu8miqym6kcb1dt\settings).
16:35:57.940 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on cp_proj class cache for build file 'D:\myJobCard_SourceCode\build.gradle' (C:\Users\MY HOME\.gradle\caches\2.10\scripts\build_7pkieelf3zpr7uf7k01l63rmx\cp_proj).
16:35:57.940 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on proj class cache for build file 'D:\myJobCard_SourceCode\build.gradle' (C:\Users\MY HOME\.gradle\caches\2.10\scripts\build_7pkieelf3zpr7uf7k01l63rmx\proj).
16:35:57.940 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on cp_proj class cache for build file 'D:\myJobCard_SourceCode\android-logging-log4j-1.0.3\build.gradle' (C:\Users\MY HOME\.gradle\caches\2.10\scripts\build_7utva779gtlkclvebpnh750jk\cp_proj).
16:35:57.941 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on proj class cache for build file 'D:\myJobCard_SourceCode\android-logging-log4j-1.0.3\build.gradle' (C:\Users\MY HOME\.gradle\caches\2.10\scripts\build_7utva779gtlkclvebpnh750jk\proj).
16:35:57.941 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on cp_proj class cache for build file 'D:\myJobCard_SourceCode\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\MY HOME\.gradle\caches\2.10\scripts\build_56xn5xy2yld7cwkurxonzuovl\cp_proj).
16:35:57.942 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on proj class cache for build file 'D:\myJobCard_SourceCode\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\MY HOME\.gradle\caches\2.10\scripts\build_56xn5xy2yld7cwkurxonzuovl\proj).
16:35:57.942 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on cp_proj class cache for build file 'D:\myJobCard_SourceCode\log4j-1.2.17\build.gradle' (C:\Users\MY HOME\.gradle\caches\2.10\scripts\build_8bsoptu904i00rpm86ii2r5ih\cp_proj).
16:35:57.942 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on proj class cache for build file 'D:\myJobCard_SourceCode\log4j-1.2.17\build.gradle' (C:\Users\MY HOME\.gradle\caches\2.10\scripts\build_8bsoptu904i00rpm86ii2r5ih\proj).
16:35:57.944 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
16:35:57.945 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 8 (avg: 0.006 secs, total: 0.049 secs)
16:35:57.946 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.ResolutionResultsStoreFactory] Deleted 2 resolution results binary files in 0.003 secs
16:35:57.946 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedRepositoryFactory]                                                                                                                        In-memory dependency metadata cache closed. Repos cached: 41, cache instances: 5, modules served from cache: 702, artifacts: 49
16:35:57.946 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-artifacts.bin (C:\Users\MY HOME\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.16\module-artifacts.bin)
16:35:57.947 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-metadata.bin (C:\Users\MY HOME\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.16\module-metadata.bin)
16:35:57.947 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache artifact-at-repository.bin (C:\Users\MY HOME\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.16\artifact-at-repository.bin)
16:35:57.947 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on artifact cache (C:\Users\MY HOME\.gradle\caches\modules-2).
16:35:57.949 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache Plugin Resolution Cache (C:\Users\MY HOME\.gradle\caches\2.10\plugin-resolution) was closed 0 times.
16:35:57.950 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonManager] Stopping 0 compiler daemon(s).
16:35:57.950 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonManager] Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
16:35:57.952 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] The daemon has finished executing the build.
16:36:45.960 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientInputForwarder] Dispatching close input message: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput@66269a8
16:36:45.966 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 17: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput
16:36:45.971 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient] Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=22532, address=[dcdd43f4-9cff-4985-9851-6f1b9dfca80e port:65391, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]], idle=false, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=b61dca0a-e70c-4dec-98ed-b69fe929e57e,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\MY HOME\.gradle\daemon,pid=22532,idleTimeout=120000,daemonOpts=-Xmx4096m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).
16:36:45.977 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Finished
```

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1.Is this Android studio version matters for obfuscation (minifyEnabled true) ?
Are there any online or offline tools for encrypting the APK ?
Please suggest me.
I have wasted a lot of time on this.
Please help me with this.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried `-keep class java.com.formsEngine.tasks.FormLoaderTask`?

Comment: Hi Krypton, Thank you for your response.I will try now...

Comment: It didn't worked Krypton...

Comment: [Obfuscation in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290023/obfuscation-in-android-studio)

Comment: @RonTLV, I have checked it.I am trying the same kind but it is not working...

Comment: What are the duplicate classes? Do you have those relative logs?

Comment: @shizhen, updated the Question.Please check the complete log while building the apk with "minifyEnabled true"

Answer (score 1):

> Well... As you haven't mentioned yet, to the ant, to pro-guard your app, That's why it is not able to obfuscate it. Use explicitly `useProguard true`

---

Need a simple example of app gradle build file...? Find it below as it is of my project :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxxxxxxxxxcccccccvvvvvv.apps.firebase"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        shrinkResources true
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

---

> Now what it means in wording :
>   It will only `obfuscate` your code in release of your project; which means you have to build your release apk.

### How to test...? obfuscation happened or not?

Here we go...

1. Unzip apk file from linux or mac os terminal as: unzip apk_name
2. You will get your project files extracted... find dex file
3. Use dex2jar to convert it into jar
4. Read that jar file with JD-UI app
5. You will see all your java classes and core code files
6. Yes.... look neat.... Its a code.... But with obfuscation

> Hmmmm... Hope it helps

### Edit : 2

In the pro-guard rules files... Do not try to program it like code, just keep some classes which are not so important as :
-keep public class OpenSource

Thats it.

### Edit : 3

Most importantly you should and must as a beginner use default pro-guard file set by android studio or whichever your IDE; while creating the project. like :

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

### Edit : 4

It is a good habit to create a new sample project, learn how to implement any concept, once we are hands on it and cleared the concept..., Open the main project and implement it within..., As ... As of now , we are mastered the concept.

### Edit : 5

It is always recommended to use Android Studio than any other IDE as it is officially by google as android is.. And it must be latest and updated IDE with minimum api 26 enabled. as google made compulsory last week that to upload apps on google play apps must target api level 26.

Also it helps to your project to get it build error free as all the latest dependencies are there along with patches.

Comment: Hi Sandhya, Thanks for your response. I will definetly try this and let you know...If I add "minifyEnabled false" it is not obfuscating, if I add "minifyEnabled true" it is giving above exception as mentioned.

Comment: How much minifyEnabled can minify your code...? It is not as important as pro-guarding your code. obfuscation and minifying both are different. But as you mentioned your code is not getting obfuscated, i given the answer in much depth.

Comment: I have edited my Question.Please check application build.gradle file.

Comment: Do not use pro-guard or minify for debug as it is intended for testing purpose. Use only in release; with standard proguard file. Look Edit 3

Comment: Sure, It is giving same exception which I have mentioned even If I add "minifyEnabled true, useProguard true, shrinkResources true" in release mode.

Comment: Give it a try on sample empty project with some mainactivity code of getting permissions from user. use above steps. release. unzip. dex2jar. JD-UI. Have a keen look over code.

Comment: I have tried many links but none worked.Any more options to Obfuscate ?

Comment: Sample project obfuscated "minifyEnabled true" working in both debug and release modes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to delete the `.idea` and `.gradle` directory under your project root directory and restart your Android Studio and **re-sync** your project. And change your `build.gradle` settings as below:

   ```
   android {
       ...
       compileSdkVersion 24
       buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

       defaultConfig {
           ...
           targetSdkVersion 24 
           ...
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Double check all the libraries inside `libs` to see if you have any duplicate ones with `compile xxx`, because you have below library dependencies declaration.

   ```
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   ```

   This may cause the duplicate inclusion of libraries, for example, `compile files('libs/gson-2.6.2.jar')`. Try to remove all the duplicate libraries.

Comment: hey I have tried but no luck, giving below exceptions Error:PARSE ERROR:
Error:bad descriptor: charOffset
Error:...while parsing attributes[2]
Error:...while parsing methods[1]
Error:...while parsing org/b/a/g.class
Error:1 error; aborting
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Prgm Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: It is different error from your original post which means another problem

Comment: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Prgm Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 - this Exception is same for both cases

Comment: The error of168 duplicate classs definition disappeared?

Comment: Use `gradlew assembleRelease --info --debug` to get more debug information about the error.

Comment: Hi shizhen, I am working with other issues.Where to add this statement "gradlew assembleRelease --info --debug" ?

Comment: This is a gradle build command line to tell you more information about your build errors. Your current error logs is not comprehensive and not easy to investigate further.

Comment: I have edited the question, added exception from command line.Please check @shizhen

Answer (score 0):

ever considered upgrading from Android Studio `1.5.1` to `3.1.3` ??

and I've double-checked, that this is not a question from a few years ago.

it reads `bad descriptor: charOffset`, which hints for errors in the `build.gradle`... most likely, that the referenced `proguard-android-optimize.txt` does not even exist within the file-system.

you'd have to reference the ProGuard configuration rules alike:

```
proguardFile "${project.rootDir}/proguard-rules.pro"
// proguardFile "${project.rootDir}/some-more-rules.pro"
shrinkResources true
minifyEnabled true
```

Comment: Hi Martin, Thank you for your response.I have to change proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'  to proguardFile "${project.rootDir}/proguard-rules.pro" in app level build.gradle file ?

Comment: @Naveen yes, usually this would apply to the `release` build configuration (just make sure the file exists, where it is being referenced). and downloading a newer version of the IDE would make sense, because much changed since then.

Comment: I have checked in debug mode with above code which you mentioned, giving exception Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\myJobCard_SourceCode\proguard-rules.pro (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: @Naveen you have to put that file there, or adjust the path, so that it can be found. here I have several `.pro` files, for example `${project.rootDir}/proguard/google.pro`, so that I can organize these as rule-sets, in order to know where to look for.

Comment: I have one ,pro file that is "proguard-rules.pro", located in app.Hope you will help me on this Martin.

Comment: Warning:2 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code (http://proguard/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)Warning:there were 18 unresolved references to library class members.You probably need to update the library versions.
(http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: correct the above warnings first.:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug FAILED

Comment: Above exception when adding manual file path of proguard file in app level build.gradle.

Comment: @Naveen these are no exceptions - and it confirms that ProGuard is working. these are just warnings, that some of the classes defined in the ProGuard configuration do not exists in the project and that you need to remove them from the configuration; it tells you exactly what to do: "correct the above warnings first". please accept my answer.

Comment: ,Sure but I cannot able to build the apk when I set minifyEnabled to true.Giving the above exception.I need to build apk with minifyEnabled true.