# Android studio: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I get the following error whenever I am trying to compile-

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
>       Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
>       This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
>       If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
>       targetCompatibility = '1.7'
>       sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
>       to that submodule's build.gradle file.

My build.gradle file is as follows-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sbcappium"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' 
    exclude 'META-INF/notice'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
 compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
apply plugin: 'android'
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'

androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'

})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile group: 'net.time4j', name: 'time4j-android', version: '3.24-2016i'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/cglib-nodep-3.2.4.jar')


compile files('libs/commons-exec-1.3.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-io-2.5.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')

compile files('libs/gson-2.8.0.jar')
compile files('libs/guava-21.0.jar')
compile files('libs/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar')


compile files('libs/htmlunit-driver-2.26.jar')

compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.6.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.5.3.jar')
compile files('libs/java-client-5.0.0-BETA8.jar')

compile files('libs/jetty-io-9.4.1.v20170120.jar')
compile files('libs/jetty-util-9.4.1.v20170120.jar')
compile files('libs/jna-4.1.0.jar')

compile files('libs/junit-4.12.jar')

compile files('libs/phantomjsdriver-1.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/sac-1.3.jar')
compile files('libs/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/serializer-2.7.2.jar')
compile files('libs/websocket-api-9.4.3.v20170317.jar')
compile files('libs/websocket-client-9.4.3.v20170317.jar')
compile files('libs/websocket-common-9.4.3.v20170317.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'}
```

I have tried all the solutions provide in the following links, but nothing worked for me-

1. [Android: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020413/android-dex-cannot-parse-version-52-byte-code)
2. [Andrioid Studio - Error converting bytecode to dex, Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40645390/andrioid-studio-error-converting-bytecode-to-dex-cause-dex-cannot-parse-vers)

What is wrong with my build.gradle file? Please keep in mind that I have made every possible alteration to the gradle file according to the solutions provided in the above two links.

Comment: Change compatibility to `1.8` You have a dependency that required 1.8, but you are trying to compile with 1.7

Comment: @MattClark - I have tried that earlier, did not work.

Comment: In what way did not work? What happened? Please quote any error message verbatim.

Comment: @OleV.V. I have provided the error above as it appears. Whenever I go to run the main java file I get the above error.

Comment: Hm, maybe this is about the `java-client-5.0.0-BETA8`, see also the compilation settings at its [build.gradle-file](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/build.gradle) It seems to have been compiled with Java-8.

Answer (score 0):

please add this code to your build.gradle

```
  compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
```

I hope your problem be solved