# Error:Error converting bytecode to dex Android Studio 3.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I already read this article and all other related: [Android: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020413/android-dex-cannot-parse-version-52-byte-code)

But still I have next issue while doing build:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
```

Android Studio 3.0.1

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
```

When I do: gradlew installDebug - it installs application to device.
But when I start application from Run/Debug - it fails with this error.
I am using Java SDK 1.8 and JAVA_HOME path is defined to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151.

Does any one know how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Build... Clean Project then run the project again
This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

There's some IDE related .idea files that must be changed also, using the IDE the following changes it to 1.8:

Go to File... Project Structure...

Select the app module and in the main tab (properties) select Target Compatibility to 1.8